# Form elements in a mess when i switching between it

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, uiswitch

The elements of the registration form are as on the mockup, as soon as I click on the switcher to switch to the login form, the elements of the form are in a complete mess, and even when I switch back to the registration form, the elements do not become as they were, what can it be?

Comment: there is no codepen link.

Comment: its already added

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid posting external links to code like CodePens, because links can go dead over time which would make this question no longer valuable to others with the same problem. Instead try to create a [mcve] and embed it within the question itself using a StackSnippet if possible.

Comment: Your `#registration_form` has `display: flex` in the CSS initially, but your JS does not switch it back from `none` to _that_, but to `block` instead.

Comment: Thanks,Registration form is already set up but Login stand like this yet

Comment: whats can be a problem here

Comment: Same issue - only for your login form you forgot to make it a flex element and set `flex-direction: column;` to begin with.

Comment: Give your login form the same class as your registration form. it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes,it working,but please one last question: why the modal window does not adjust to the form and there is so much free unnecessary space under the login form,but with register everything's cool,height: auto,100%  - is not working?what can be a problem

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS code should be **display = "flex"** instead of "block".
Also, you need to give **class="registration_form"** to your login_form.

```
function showRegistrationForm() {
  document.getElementById("registration_form").style.display = "flex";
  document.getElementById("login_form").style.display = "none";
}

// Функція для показу форми входу
function showLoginForm() {
  document.getElementById("registration_form").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("login_form").style.display = "flex";
}
```